# Is there a way to determine what kernel version a kernel module was compiled against?

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

I have recently been playing around with creating kernel modules using some crosstools for an embedded setup.

It would be helpful to me in future to have the ability to identify the version of the kernel that these modules have been built against. I can find no information online about this so I am starting to think that perhaps it is not possible.

So my question is are there any command line utilities that can ascertain the kernel version headers that a *.ko file was compiled against?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Execute the command `modinfo <kernel_module_name>` and look for **vermagic**

> **shw@shw:/tmp #** modinfo btrfs
>   filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/fs/btrfs/btrfs.ko
>   license:        GPL
>   alias:          devname:btrfs-control
>   alias:          char-major-10-234
>   alias:          fs-btrfs 
>   srcversion:     EA2C07F0B841AE2A6D8F91F
>   depends:        libcrc32c,raid6_pq,xor
>   intree:         Y
>   *vermagic:       3.13.0-36-generic* SMP mod_unload modversions 686   <==
>   signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
>   sig_key:        FF:9A:DA:11:B8:55:51:6A:72:98:65:9D:4E:3F:BB:76:C5:4A:D3:30
>   sig_hashalgo:   sha512